# Rails Active Storage without asset pipeline

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activestorage

I am switching from Paperclip to Active Storage in a Rails project. I have successfully done the migration. I have confirmed in a view that my model has an attachment but I'm getting an error which I think is regarding files Active Storage expects to be in the asset pipeline. This project doesn't use the asset pipeline.

So when I do the following in the view.

```
<%= image_tag @Entryform.logo %>
```

I get a valid tag with a URL but then things go wrong.

Console output is

```
Started GET "/assets/jquery_ujs.self.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-07-31 10:56:30 -0500
Processing by ActiveStorage::BlobsController#show as HTML
  Parameters: {"signed_id"=>"eyJfcmFpbHMiOnsibWVzc2FnZSI6IkJBaHBCdz09IiwiZXhwIjpudWxsLCJwdXIiOiJibG9iX2lkIn19--18406ee7b69394ebf89cb81d67eb2513b2ee6e45", "filename"=>"2-1"}
Started GET "/assets/jquery.self.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-07-31 10:56:30 -0500
ActiveStorage::Blob Load (12.0ms)  SELECT  `active_storage_blobs`.* FROM `active_storage_blobs` WHERE `active_storage_blobs`.`id` = 2 LIMIT 1
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 15ms (ActiveRecord: 12.0ms)
```

I ran the above query and it returns the correct record. That those js files are not in the asset pipeline is the only thing I see wrong here.

The error I'm getting is the following.

```
NoMethodError - undefined method `url_expires_in' for nil:NilClass:
```

Is it possible to do this without the asset pipeline or is this error due to something else?